# Counting objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have JSON:

```
var data = {
    "conv0": {
        "id":"d647ed7a5f254462af0a7dc05c75817e",
        "channelId":"emulator",
        "user": {
            "id":"2c1c7fa3",
            "name":"User1"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "isGroup":false,
            "id":"8a684db8",
            "name":"Conv1"
        },
        "bot": {
            "id":"56800324",
            "name":"Bot1"
        },
        "serviceUrl":"http://localhost:9000",
        "useAuth":true
    },
    "conv1": {
        "id":"af77cf19d07749c8aacaed81528abf7a",
        "channelId":"emulator",
        "user": {
            "id":"2c1c7fa3",
            "name":"User1"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "isGroup":false,
            "id":"8a684db8",
            "name":"Conv1"
        },
        "bot": {
            "id":"56800324",
            "name":"Bot1"
        },
        "serviceUrl":"http://localhost:9000",
        "useAuth":true
     }
}
```

It was generated with the help of node-js-db. Basicly, it is a JSON file with conv0 and conv1 json obj here. I need to count how many objects (conv0, conv1) I have in this JSON. 
I have tried to use

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

But it counted all keys, but I need only objects. Is there any way to count them?

Comment: It's invalid JSON

Comment: your data is not valid write it properly

Comment: add a `{` before the first "isGroup":

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: It's returning `2` as there are (conv0 and conv1). So what else do you want ?

Comment: "Object.keys(data).length" returns 7, not 2. ALso this JSON is generated automatically from Botframework with node-js-db. I am not usre if I need to correct it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to count the top level keys. If so, you can try this:

```
var json = '{"a":{"b":1},"b":{"h":3}}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
var c = 0;
for (var i in jsonObj) {
    c += 1;
}
```

c will contain the count

Comment: Thanks, that really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function to count objects

```js
var obj = {
  "conv0": {
    "id": "d647ed7a5f254462af0a7dc05c75817e",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "user": {
      "id": "2c1c7fa3",
      "name": "User1"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "isGroup": false,
      "id": "8a684db8",
      "name": "Conv1"
    },
    "bot": {
      "id": "56800324",
      "name": "Bot1"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000",
    "useAuth": true
  },

  "conv1": {
    "id": "af77cf19d07749c8aacaed81528abf7a",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "user": {
      "id": "2c1c7fa3",
      "name": "User1"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "isGroup": false,
      "id": "8a684db8",
      "name": "Conv1"
    },
    "bot": {
      "id": "56800324",
      "name": "Bot1"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000",
    "useAuth": true
  }
}


var c = 0;

function count(data) {
  for (var p in data) {
    if (typeof data[p] == 'object') {
      c++;
      count(data[p]);
    }
  }
}

count(obj)
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a data object and you want to count how many properties of this object are themselves objects.  If this is correct then

`Object.keys(data).filter(function(k){return data[k] instanceof Object}).length`

should do it.

Alternatively if you want to count all properties with a 'conv...' name then you could use

`Object.keys(data).filter(function(k){return /^conv/.test(k)}).length`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to check no of objects in your JSON object or Modern browsers have method to count objects.

I presume that data is your JSON object and please correct your JSON object first( missing { before 'isgroup')

**1 Custom Method**

```
function check(data){
 var count=0;
 for(var key in data){
 ++count;
}
alert("total size : "+count);
}
```

**2. Modern Browser Method**

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

Answer (score -1):

The JOSN is invalid, i corrected Use the following JSON

```
 var data = {
   "conv0": {
    "id": "d647ed7a5f254462af0a7dc05c75817e",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "user": { "id": "2c1c7fa3", "name": "User1" },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": false,
        "id": "8a684db8",
        "name": "Conv1"
    },
    "bot": { "id": "56800324", "name": "Bot1" },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000",
    "useAuth": true
},

 "conv1": {
    "id": "af77cf19d07749c8aacaed81528abf7a",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "user": { "id": "2c1c7fa3", "name": "User1" },
    "conversation": { "isGroup": false, "id": "8a684db8", "name": "Conv1" },
    "bot": { "id": "56800324", "name": "Bot1" },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000",
    "useAuth": true
    }
 }
```